# Consider the code given below, Is there any way to acces the variable "iry" from the innerClassMethod() if the variable name "iry" is changed to "i"?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Consider the code given below, Is there any way to acces the final variable "iry" "iry" from the innerClassMethod() if the variable name "iry" is changed to "i"? This may seem to be a duplicate question as "accsess to shadowed variable" but it has not yet been accepted satisfactorily by the question asker!

```
class Outer{
    int i = 10;
    public void m1(){
        final int iry = 100;
        class Inner{
            int i= 20;
            public void innerClassMethod(){
                System.out.println(this.i);
                System.out.println(Outer.this.i);
                System.out.println(iry);
            }
        }
        Inner obj =new Inner();
        obj.innerClassMethod();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, please be sure to format and indent your code in a readable, consistent way. (It's best to do that when *not* asking for help, too. :-) ) *(I've done it for you this time.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I got this as, he want to access current 'iry' variable if it's name is 'i'. isn't it

Comment: @janith1024: Somehow I read it (the dupetarget) another way, but a second read suggests I read it wrong. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am so sorry for the inconvenience...wouldn't repeat it the next time...thank you for reformatting the code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you got it what I meant to say...can I have the answer please?

Comment: Changing a variable's name doesn't change its scope or visibility. Unclear what you're asking, or alternatively why you haven't just tried it.

Comment: @EJP: In this case, it would, because he OP is changing the name to `i`, which means it'll be shadowed by the inner class's member called `i`.

Comment: @DeepRoy: See the answers on the linked question, that's why it's linked. :-)

Comment: got it  @T.J.Crowder the answer is that there is no way to access the variable in such a case. Thank you